# Функция времени в MSSQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, дата, время

Коллеги, помогите. Есть дата. Нужно достать из нее только время (чч:мм:сс) для того, чтобы провести сравнение. Например, разбить данные: до 7 утра, с 7 до 14, и после 14 дня.

Функция time() не срабатывает. (MSSQL 2005)

```
...
REPLACE((SELECT cast(**time(act6.time_to)** as nvarchar(max)) + ' * ' + cast(ROUND((
...

Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 107
time не является известным имя встроенной функции.
```

Есть другие варианты?

Comment: @Mike эта функция есть только начиная с 2008-й версии

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, act6.time_to, 0), act6.time_to)
```

Поскольку в SQL Server 2005 нет типа time, будет использована дата `1900-01-01`, но в вашем случае для целей сравнения это не существенно.

Если время нужно в виде строки: `CONVERT(CHAR(8), act6.time_to, 108)`.